# Does $\mathsf{Ind}_\lambda^\mu(\mathsf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C)) = \mathsf{Ind}_\kappa^\mu(\mathcal C)$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories, accessible-categories

$\newcommand\Ind{\mathsf{Ind}}\newcommand\Ord{\mathsf{Ord}}\newcommand\Psh{\mathsf{Psh}}$For $\kappa \leq \lambda \leq \Ord$ regular cardinals and $\mathcal C$ an essentially small category, let $\Ind_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C)$ be the free completion of $\mathcal C$ under $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimits. So $\Ind_\kappa^{\Ord}(\mathcal C) = \Ind_\kappa(\mathcal C)$ is the usual free completion of $\mathcal C$ under $\kappa$-filtered colimits.

An explicit construction of $\Ind_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C)$ is given by taking the smallest full subcategory of the presheaf category $\Psh(\mathcal C)$ which contains the representables and is closed under $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimits. In other words, there is a monotonic, inflationary endofunction $I_\kappa^\lambda$ on full subcategories of $\Psh(\mathcal C)$ where $I_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal D)$ comprises those objects which are $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimits of objects of $\mathcal D$; then $\Ind_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C) = \cup_{\alpha \in \Ord} (I_\kappa^\lambda)^\alpha(\mathcal C)$ is the least fixed-point of $I_\kappa^\lambda$ above the full subcategory of representables $\mathcal C \subseteq \Psh(\mathcal C)$, given by iterating $I_\kappa^\lambda$ transfinitely.

**Questions:**

1. For regular cardinals $\kappa \leq \lambda \leq \Ord$, when do we have $\Ind_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C) = I_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C)$? That is, when is it the case that a $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimit of $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimits of representables is already a $\lambda$-small, $\kappa$-filtered colimit of representables?

It is well-known that a sufficient criterion is that $\lambda = \Ord$. I suspect that when $\lambda < \Ord$, the answer is "not always". I believe it also suffices for $\mathcal C$ to have $\kappa$-small colimits. I'm interested in a sufficient criterion that holds for all $\mathcal C$. I suspect it may suffice to have $\kappa \triangleleft \lambda$ (that's the "[sharply below](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sharply+smaller+cardinal)" relation).

2. For regular cardinals $\kappa \leq \lambda \leq \mu \leq \Ord$, when do we have $\Ind_\lambda^\mu(\Ind_\kappa^\lambda(\mathcal C)) \simeq \Ind_\kappa^\mu(\mathcal C)$?

I suspect again that the answer is "not always", but that a sufficient criterion may be for the pairs $(\kappa,\lambda)$, $(\lambda,\mu)$, and $(\kappa,\mu)$ to each satisfy the sufficient criterion of (1). I'm particularly interested in the case $\kappa = \omega < \lambda < \mu = \Ord$, where I suspect that this always holds (keeping in mind that $\omega \triangleleft \lambda$ for all regular $\lambda$).

I would be interested to know a reference for the answers to (1) and (2).

Comment: Regarding iterated ind-completion, see proposition 3.10(iv) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6659).

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, this is great! Let me see if I've got this straight. If we assume (in my terminology) that $C$ is idempotent-complete and $I_\kappa^\lambda(C) = Ind_\kappa^\lambda(C)$ (i.e. $(\kappa,\lambda)$ answers to Question 1), then the inclusion $C \to Ind_\kappa^\lambda(C)$ is clearly (in your terminology) a $(\kappa,\kappa,\lambda)$-accessibly-generated extension. In this case, your Prop 3.10(iv) says (in my terminology) that if $\kappa \triangleleft \lambda$, then $Ind_\kappa^{Ord}(C) = Ind_\lambda^{Ord}(Ind_\kappa^\lambda(C))$, so that $(\kappa,\lambda,Ord)$ answers to Question 2.

Comment: This reduces the most important case of Question 2 to Question 1, which is fantastic!

Comment: @ZhenLin By your Prop 3.5, if $\kappa \triangleleft \lambda$, then the $\lambda$-presentable objects of $Ind_\kappa(C)$ form (in your terminology) a $(\kappa,\lambda)$-accessibly-generated category. Therefore (in my terminology, and assuming that $C$ has split idempotents) $I_\kappa^\lambda(C) = Ind_\kappa^\lambda(C)$. Thus by your work, if $C$ is essentially small with split idempotents and $\kappa \triangleleft \lambda$, then $(\kappa,\lambda,Ord)$ answers to Question 1 and (hence) to Question 2. If you write this, or even just "answered in the comments" as an answer, I'll gladly accept!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked myself the same questions while working on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6659) [[TAC](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/31/2/31-02abs.html)].
It seemed to me that the way to answer questions like this is to embed $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})$ into the usual $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$, use known results for accessible categories, then restrict back to $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})$.
This is possible when $\kappa \trianglelefteq \lambda$ due to the following fact, which is basically proposition 3.5 in op. cit.: $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})$ is precisely the full subcategory of $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$ spanned by the $\lambda$-presentable objects.

Thus, to answer question 1: if idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split and $\kappa \trianglelefteq \lambda$, then every object in $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})$ is a colimit for a $\lambda$-small $\kappa$-filtered diagram of objects in $\mathcal{C}$, because every $\lambda$-presentable object in $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$ is such a colimit by a theorem of Makkai and Paré.

Similarly, to answer question 2: if idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split and $\kappa \trianglelefteq \lambda \trianglelefteq \mu$, then $\textbf{Ind}_\lambda^\mu (\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})) \simeq \textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\mu (\mathcal{C})$, because we have $\textbf{Ind}_\lambda (\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})) \simeq \textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$ by proposition 3.10(iv) in op. cit., which is proven by reducing to the case where $\kappa = \lambda$.

(A side remark: for fixed $\mathcal{C}$, $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa^\lambda (\mathcal{C})$ is contravariant in $\kappa$ and covariant in $\lambda$, so personally I would reverse the use of subscript and superscript in this notation.)

Comment: Thanks again! When I went to look up the result of Makkai and Pare you use for Prop 3.5 (their Prop 2.3.11), my copy of their book immediately fell open to that proposition! So perhaps I should have been able to work this out :) But even being able to guess the right answer was probably due anyway to half-remembered conversations with you on this topic from years ago. The point about variance is well-taken -- although the opposite convention is sometimes used, e.g. by Riehl and Verity in [Theory and Practice of Reedy Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6871) (see first line of p. 5).

Comment: In this case, the mnemonic for me was that $\lambda$ is bigger than $\kappa$ and it's conventional to view bigger ordinals / cardinals as lying "above" smaller ones, so I put the bigger one as a superscript. It also meant the subscript ended up in the same place as the usual usage for $Ind_\kappa$. I hadn't thought of it, but you're right -- the variance does also seem super-relevant to making a good choice of notation here. For one thing, it's a good reason not to be using a double superscript or a double subscript.

Comment: As I'm rambling on anyway, maybe I'll add that although in differential geometry the subscripts are called "covariant" tensors and the superscripts "contravariant", the terminology has always seemed backwards to me, since differential forms are subscripted and are contravariantly functorial in smooth maps, while vector fields are superscripted and covariantly functorial in smooth maps. The real examples of contravariant functors getting superscripts are things like exponentials and duals.

Comment: The matter in differential geometry is confusing. My way of thinking about it: a "real" vector field is neither covariant nor contravariant but invariant. Coordinate basis vectors are covariant, so they are subscripted: $\partial_i x$. Coordinate basis covectors are contravariant, so they are superscripted: $\mathrm{d} x^i$. The _components_ of a vector wrt the coordinate basis are contravariant, so they are superscripted. The _components_ of a covector wrt the coordinate basis are covariant, so they are subscripted.